# POP account issues with El Capitan

Tags: pop

Why is my POP account not working after I upgraded to El Capitan? I sometimes can get mail and then it stops working so the problem is intermittent.

Answer (score 3):

Think I may have found a solution. Went to mail preferences - then accounts - then advanced - then UNCHECKED "automatically detect and maintain account settings"... my mail seems to be coming in without disruption...

Comment: Yes. That's been the case since Yosemite, if not before - the 'maintenance' seems only good for IMAP accounts, POP it seems to break

Answer (score 0):

When I contacted GoDaddy thinking it was their shenanigans that caused the POP to stop, he advised me that El Cap was at fault. He wanted to "fix" it by charging me an additional $97/yr. I said no and after whining a little, he gave me the same instructions posted here. However, he did tell me this fix was only temporary.

Comment: Shoot.... thought it was good.... if anyone else has a solution please post!